# In JMETER session id is not getting correlated from HTTP Request path

Tags: jmeter

`/projectname/frameset?__report=WEB-INF/reports/MetricsReportDevDeplTrunc.rptdesign&__showtitle=false&projectId=${prjid}&accountId=-1&programId=-1&categoryId=131&contextPath=/projname&serverName=projname-abc.com&serverPort=8080&startDate=2013-06-01&endDate=2013-06-30&/${session_id}`

Here if we give the session id its throwing an error as illegal character in path..
Also after escaping the `$` the same session id value is not getting displayed in debug sampler..
This is a path for the report to get displayed in BIRT report viewer, as a result the birt report viewer always throws a error as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>
                BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects( ) 
            </faultcode><faultstring>
                The viewing session is not available or has expired.
            </faultstring><detail><ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">projname-abc.com</ns1:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please provide some answer to this query...
Prompt response is highly appreciated in this regard...

Answer (score 0):

Seems the session you are trying to use is not present at the http request. Add the view result listener in jmeter and see the session id on the response.